# rspec / factory girl causing SystemStackError in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rspec, factory-bot

I'm getting this error when running rspec on a spec file:

MYPATH/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Here is the line it is called on:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Here are my versions of relevant gems:

factory_girl 2.1.0

rails 3.0.10

rspec 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove line

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Answer (score 0):

or remove:

```
FactoryGirl.reload
```

This is what solved this issue for me